# Contador de visita para links únicos

Tags: php

Gostaria de fazer um contador visualizações/acessos de páginas que pegassem o link.

Ex.:

> noticia.php?p=1 - 33 visualizações
>
> noticia.php?p=2 - 14 visualizações
>
> noticia.php?p=3 - 08 visualizações

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O que pretende de fato? Se for gerar um relatório simples, basta verificar o IP do usuário antes gravar de somar +1.

Comment: Pretendo exibi-lo em uma página que contém uma notícia, sinalizando quantas pessoa leram ou entraram no link.

Comment: Antes de atualizar com +1, use uma tabela auxiliar para gravar o IP de quem acessou a noticia. Se o IP não estiver na tabela você soma +1, caso contrário, considere que o usuário já leu.

Comment: Gera uma session assim que o usuário acessar o site não faça a contagem por IP, grave a session e coloque como um contador, considere que o mesmo computador pode ser compartilhado e/ou uma rede compartilhada que está sob o mesmo IP.

Comment: @DiegoVieira, não considerou que o usuário pode remover o cookie da sessão?

Comment: @PapaCharlie http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0

Comment: Pessoal, eu estou precisando de um script que conte as visitas nos posts de um site, queria usar tipo um get url, mas não sei muito sobre PHP. Se necessário posso usar banco de dados. Alguém por acaso teria esse script?

Comment: @DiegoVieira, acho que você não sabe que para ter uma sessão precisa de um cookie. O PHP usa um cookie chamado PHPSESSID para identificar o usuário. Basta remover o cookie.

Comment: vai ter que usar banco de dados sim, independente se for usar session do PHP, se o apache reiniciar você perderia tudo que esta na Session.